# Extracting TOP directory from from file path in R

Tags: r, regex

I need guidance on how to extract the first (or) top directory from a given path. This includes the first slash and the last slash.  For example, in the path: "/chemicalemergencies/category/test-page1.html", I need to extract "/chemicalemergencies/"  I've used str_extract and regex to identify the pattern, but the problem is that it is returning ANY match.  This is problematic if the URL has duplicate folders.  So for example, if the path is "/chemicalemergencies/category/chemicalemergencies/test-page1.html", it will return BOTH the results, when I only need the first one.  How do make pattern detect stop after the first match in the string?

```
Sys.time()
#i=4
for (i in 1:nrow(wwwdevurls)) {
  pathextract_wwwdev <- str_extract(wwwdevurls[i,3],"\\/([A-z0-9]+)\\/")
  pathextract_wwwdev.df[i,1] <- pathextract_wwwdev #Load pathextract into pathextract.df
  pathextract_wwwdev.df[i,2] <- wwwdevurls[i,1] #Load CIO into pathextract.df
}
Sys.time()
```

Comment: Use `str_extract(wwwdevurls, "(?<=^/)[^/]+")` or even `str_extract(wwwdevurls, "[^/]+")`. `str_extract` searches for a single match only.

Comment: Thank you - will the regex, "[^/]+", capture the beginning and ending slashes too?  I need both of those returned in the match.

Comment: Then use `str_extract(wwwdevurls, "/[^/]+/")` or a more explicit `str_extract(wwwdevurls, "^/[^/]+/")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^[^/]*(/[^/]*/)`
where the first directory encased in slashes is in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your paths *always* start with a slash, you can use:

```
sub("(/.*?/).*", "\\1", path)
"/chemicalemergencies/"
```